# How to use ifelse function in r

Tags: r, if-statement

```
surveywithoutmissing <- data.frame(Collaboration_A = rep(c(0 "times", 1 "time", 2-4 "times", >4 "times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 20, 26, 11, 118)),
             Collaboration_B = rep(c(0 "times", 1 "time", 2-4 "times",>4 "times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 22, 33, 16, 104)),
             Collaboration_C = rep(c(0 "times", 1 "time", 2-4 "times", >4 "times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 16, 23, 9, 127)),
             Collaboration_D = rep(c(0 "times", 1 "time", 2-4 "times", >4 "times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 24, 12, 4, 135)))
```

This will not run and it gives the error response:

`Error: unexpected ')' in ""times" = c(0, 24, 12, 4, 135))"`

Comment: What does this have to do with ifelse?

Comment: Let's start small, this is not a valid syntax: `c(0 "times")`. What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you are trying to do. But it seems to me that you try to repeat each element (e.g., "0", ">4") with different numbers. That is, you seem to repeat "0", "1", "2-4", ">4", NA with different number of repetitions for each collaboration. Here I took care of Collaboration_A and B.

```
# Set up the number of repetition
ana <- c(0, 20, 26, 11, 118)
bobby <- c(0, 22, 33, 16, 104)

foo <- data.frame(Collaboration_A = rep(c("0", "1", "2-4", ">4", NA), ana),
                  Collaboration_B = rep(c("0", "1", "2-4", ">4", NA), bobby),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the word "time" and "times" to be included, they need to go inside the quotes.

```
surveywithoutmissing <- data.frame(Collaboration_A = rep(c("0 times", "1 time", "2-4 times", ">4 times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 20, 26, 11, 118)),
             Collaboration_B = rep(c("0 times", "1 time", "2-4 times", ">4 times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 22, 33, 16, 104)),
             Collaboration_C = rep(c("0 times", "1 time", "2-4 times", ">4 times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 16, 23, 9, 127)),
             Collaboration_D = rep(c("0 times", "1 time", "2-4 times", ">4 times", NA),
                                   "times" = c(0, 24, 12, 4, 135)))
```

which produces

```
 > surveywithoutmissing
    Collaboration_A Collaboration_B Collaboration_C
1            1 time          1 time          1 time
2            1 time          1 time          1 time
3            1 time          1 time          1 time
4            1 time          1 time          1 time
5            1 time          1 time          1 time
6            1 time          1 time          1 time
7            1 time          1 time          1 time
8            1 time          1 time          1 time
9            1 time          1 time          1 time
10           1 time          1 time          1 time
11           1 time          1 time          1 time
12           1 time          1 time          1 time
13           1 time          1 time          1 time
14           1 time          1 time          1 time
15           1 time          1 time          1 time
16           1 time          1 time          1 time
17           1 time          1 time       2-4 times
18           1 time          1 time       2-4 times
19           1 time          1 time       2-4 times
20           1 time          1 time       2-4 times
21        2-4 times          1 time       2-4 times
22        2-4 times          1 time       2-4 times
23        2-4 times       2-4 times       2-4 times
24        2-4 times       2-4 times       2-4 times
25        2-4 times       2-4 times       2-4 times
26        2-4 times       2-4 times       2-4 times
```